# Kentico does not work on IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, kentico, x-ua-compatible

I am using Kentico 8.2 and build a new website with HTML5, new CSS styles, all Bootstrap styles and javascript.

Not surprisingly, many new styles and HTML5 tags don't work on Internet Explorer 9 and lower.

So I tried to add these tags to their "editable" master page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But doesn't work at all and I found that the meta tag has to go to the very top of the page or would not work. And on Kentico, there is no way to put this on the top. There is not-editable fixed header that Kentico always puts on top, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<link href="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetname=CorporateSite" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Is there anyway to replace this pre-written-by-Kentico header and replace with the compatible meta tag?

Thanks,

J.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Any time I add something to the HEAD on the Master Page tab of the actual master page it appears in right place and works as expected.

Comment: The order matters only for encoding tag in the head, so you should good with your tags in any position. I was doing this with Kentico 7 without any issues.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Kentico, in fact, does work it's the website you're developing does not.

Comment: Other headings that I put in the editing part works fine, like javascript or CSS references. Only meta tag does not work. and I am using Kentico 8.2.

Comment: Kentico is a tool to build a website. If I download it and just put that blank template on the internet, pretty sure it will work fine. Customers who buy Kentico are buying to build their websites. And that failed for HTML5 tags, Bootstrap and new CSS styles for older browsers.

Comment: If you have to develop for ie8 (i would push back on that and ie9) you should be using modernizer for device detection. A lot of bootstrap items won't work in ie8. Bootstrap 4 won't support IE8 at all.

https://modernizr.com/

Comment: To Mark Handy: Thanks Mark. So does this mean even the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> tagging wouldn't make the bootstrap work on IE8?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using? and what bootstrap components are you using?

With IE8 bootstrap should work, but a mobile first implementation will cause problems since IE8 doesn't understand media queries, so it will ignore them.

in ie8, look at this link: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/. it's the Bootstrap grid example. It has the meta tag with ie-edge.

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

The meta tag, meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge", should really go to the very beginning of the "head" tag. And Kentico puts all the stylesheet links that you have in their stylesheet modules linked to your site BEFORE the editable heading. This means your meta tag might get shifted down too much in the "head" tag so that it doesn't get recognized.

So, the workaround is that just build your own css files in some folder and link it yourself in the editable header (obviously after the meta tag) so that Kentico only links one, or maybe two css file links from their CSS styles module. Kentico's default websites have theme css files as well.

And, of course, put the X-UA-Compatible meta tag in the very front of editable header.

Answer (score -1):

One way to insert that to the top of all pages is you can hard code the HTML to the mother of all Portal template: \CMS\CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx

```
<%=DocType%>
<html <%=XHtmlNameSpace%> <%=XmlNamespace%>>
<head id="head" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <title id="_title" runat="server">My site</title>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tags" EnableViewState="false" />
</head>
```

It does affect all pages within the same instance, but I think it would be fine for you since you are running one site there.

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? This is basically hard coding the HTML you need to the portal parent template. And based on what you were saying, if you place the HTML between <head> and <title>, it will be there when the page is rendered.